# Javascript - Função que retorna valor de uma propriedade CSS

Tags: javascript, css, funções, propriedade

Boa noite (bom dia ou boa tarde) à todos!

Eu preciso de uma função que retorna o valor de uma propriedade css. Segue meu código:

**CSS:**

```
.teste{
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function funcao(){
 var elemento = document.getElementById("teste");
  function css(el, estilo){
     alert(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el, null).estilo);
  }
    css(elemento, "display");
}
```

Entretanto isto retorna "Undefined", então fiz a função com apenas 1 parâmetro, segue abaixo:
**JavaScript:**

```
function funcao(){
 var elemento = document.getElementById("teste");
  function css(el){
     alert(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el, null).display);
  }
    css(elemento);
}
```

Neste caso sim retorna "none". O problema é que eu precisarei buscar o valor de várias propriedades de várias classes, então a função css(el, estilo) seria perfeita (se funcionasse e retornasse o "none" no exemplo), pois assim eu poderia usar, por exemplo:

```
css(teste, display);
css(teste, visibility);
css(testeDois, display);
```

A função css() só tem o "alert" par eu testar o que retorna, no final, quando ela estiver funcionando ela não terá o "alert", ela irá apenas retornar o valor da propriedade da classe
Agradeço à todos, desde já, espero que eu tenha conseguido ser claro no meu problema
Muito obrigado!!!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode passar o estilo entre colchetes `[estilo]`:

```js
var elemento = document.getElementById("teste");

function css(el, estilo){
   console.log(estilo+':', document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el, null)[estilo]);
}

css(elemento, "display");
css(elemento, "width");
```

```css
.teste {
  width: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="teste" class="teste">
```

Mesmo que seja um objeto, o javascript permite você acessar a propriedade passando ela entra colchetes ao invés de usar `.`

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, com colchetes deu certinho, era exatamente isso que eu queria. Muito obrigado mesmo!!! :D

Comment: Bacana esta solução. Passarei a usar ela.

Answer (score 0):

Eu gostaria de agradecer à todos pela enorme ajuda que vocês me deram, tanto a solução dos colchetes quanto a do eval resolveram perfeitamente bem o meu problema. Foi ótimo ter recebido duas soluções diferentes, ambas contribuíram positivamente para o meu conhecimento. Muito obrigado à todos!!! :D

Answer (score -1):

Creio que entendi o que deseja. Já tentou usar o eval?
O eval tem por objetivo transformar sua "String" em código interpretável ao navegador.
Portanto, segue o código adaptado:

```
function funcao(){
 var elemento = document.getElementById("teste");
  function css(el, estilo){
     alert(eval("document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el, null)." + estilo));
  }
    css(elemento, "display");
}
```

Comment: Recomendo o uso de jquery, que facilitaria muito o trabalho com javascript. Neste caso, para captura de um atributo ficaria: **$('#teste').css('display');**

Comment: -1 pelo uso do eval.

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado à você também, sua resposta também atendeu perfeitamente o que eu queria. Muito obrigado!!! :D